# How to Adapt RecyclerView to D-Pad

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am attempting to adapt Android's RecyclerView to a D-Pad for TV use. I am stuck in that I am not sure when to start in the first place. Any input/solutions would be appreciated.

I have tried doing the 'android:focusablle=true' already.